# Why lattice-structured all-pole IIR filter becomes stable, if the k-coefficients satisfies $|k_i| < 1$?

Tags: filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

Why the lattice-structured all-pole IIR filter becomes stable,

if the k-coefficients satisfies $|k_i| < 1$?

Anyone who can tell me the way how to prove it, would be so thankful for me :)

ps. If anyone who has other suggestion solving differently with the proof below using Rouché's Theorem, it's welcome too!

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Please don't [cross-post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201243/why-the-lattice-structured-all-pole-iir-filter-becomes-stable-if-the-k-coeffici). The idea is that if your question is a better fit on another SE site, then the moderators where you originally posted it should be able to migrate it.

Comment: Why did you vandalize your own question? If you have further questions you can leave them as comments under my answer. Click on 'add a comment'.

Comment: I'm closing this question. The vandalism was a little strange, and it makes me unsure of what the question really was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm referring to the formulas on page 9 of [this document](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~roberts/ECE506/PresentationSlides/LatticeLadder.pdf). The denominator polynomial of the transfer function at lattice stage number $m$ is given by

$$\begin{align}A_m(z)&=A_{m-1}(z)+k_mz^{-1}B_{m-1}(z)\\
\text{with}\quad B_m(z)&=z^{-m}A_m(1/z)\\
\text{and}\quad A_0(z)&=B_0(z)=1\end{align}\tag{1}$$

where $k_m$ is the $m^{th}$ reflection coefficient.

You can prove that $A_m(z)$ has all its zeros inside the unit circle if this is the case for $A_{m-1}(z)$ and if $|k_m|<1$. This follows from [Rouché's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9's_theorem), which says that if $F(z)$ and $G(z)$ are two complex-valued functions that are analytic in and on some closed contour $C$ (which in our case is the unit circle), then $F(z)$ and $F(z)+G(z)$ have the same number of zeros inside $C$ if $|G(z)|<|F(z)|$ is satisfied on $C$.

The proof goes as follows. Define $F(z)=z^mA_{m-1}(z)$ and $G(z)=k_mz^{m-1}B_{m-1}(z)$, which, according to $(1)$, means that $F(z)+G(z)=z^mA_{m}(z)$. The zeros of $F(z)$ are the $m-1$ zeros of $A_{m-1}(z)$ plus one zero at $z=0$. Consequently, if all zeros of $A_{m-1}(z)$ are inside the unit circle, then also all zeros of $F(z)$ are inside the unit circle. From the definition of $B_m(z)$ in $(1)$ it follows that $B_{m-1}(z)$ has the same magnitude as $A_{m-1}(z)$ *on the unit circle* (i.e., for $|z|=1$). This means that $|F(z)|<|G(z)|$ is satisfied on the unit circle if $|k_m|<1$. In this case $F(z)+G(z)$ and, consequently, $A_m(z)$ have all their zeros inside the unit circle. This is the case because $F(z)$ has all its $m$ zeros inside the unit circle, and according to Rouché's theorem $F(z)+G(z)$, which has exactly $m$ zeros, has the same number of zeros inside the unit circle as $F(z)$. So $F(z)+G(z)$ must have all its $m$ zeros inside the unit circle.

This proves that all denominator polynomials $A_m(z)$ in the iteration given by $(1)$ correspond to stable transfer functions if the iteration is started with $A_0(z)=B_0(z)=1$ and if $|k_m|<1$ is satisfied for all $m$.

I've learned the above proof based on Rouché's theorem from Jackson's excellent book [Digital Filters and Signal Processing](https://books.google.nl/books?id=qtDkBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA335&vq=rouche&pg=PA335#v=onepage&q&f=false).
Another good explanation of lattice structures can be found in [this book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=e5dsEW_93ykC&lpg=PA298&ots=tXEoAEA-9l&dq=all%20pole%20iir%20lattice%20filter&pg=PA291#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Zelniker and Taylor.

Comment: @SeongBeomPark: (1) $F(z)$ and $G(z)$ are polynomials and [any polynomial is analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Examples) everywhere. (2) $|B_m(e^{j\omega})|=|e^{-jm\omega}||A_m(e^{-j\omega})|=|A_m(e^{j\omega})|$. (3) Because $A_m(z)$ has a multiple pole at $z=0$ (it is a polynomial in $z^{-1}$), so it's not analytic inside the unit circle.